# How to parse downloaded HTML files and create lists

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, beautifulsoup

I've downloaded some HTML files I am wanting to parse. I was able to parse the files but now I want to make some lists so I can make a scatter plot. I'm totally new to Python so I am not sure how to make these into lists.

I tried setting a variable equal to the text I got from the the column.

```
for y in range (1977, 2020, 1):

    tmp = random.random()*5.0
    print ('Sleep for ', tmp, ' seconds')
    time.sleep(tmp)

    url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/IND/'+ str(y) +'_games.html'
    print ('Download from :', url)

    #dowlnload
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    html = urlopen(req).read()



    fileout = 'YEARS/'+str(y)+'.html'
    print ('Save to : ', fileout, '\n')

    #save file to disk
    f = open(fileout,'w')
    f.write(html.decode('utf-8'))
    f.close()


    #parse
for year in range (1977, 2019, 1):

    filein = 'YEARS/' + str(year) + '.html'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filein), 'lxml')



    entries = soup.find_all('tr', attrs={'class' : ''})
    for entry in entries:
    #print entry
        columns = entry.find_all('td')
        if len (columns)>4 :

            #print ('C0: ', columns[4])
            where = columns[4].get_text()

            #print ('C1: ', columns[5])
            opponent = columns[5].get_text()

            #print ('C2: ', columns[6])
            WL = columns[6].get_text()

            #print ('C3: ', columns[8])
            PacerScore = columns[8].get_text()

            #print ('C4: ', columns[9])
            OpponentScore = columns[9].get_text()

            tt = where+'|::|'+opponent+'|::|'+WL+'|::|'+PacerScore+'|::|'+OpponentScore
            print (tt)


x = PacerScore
y = OpponentScore
plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

I tried using read_html from pandas as well but I was screwing something up and could not get it to work. It kept telling me feature not found.

```
#parse
for y in range (1977, 2019, 1):

    filein = 'YEARS/' + str(y) + '.html'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filein), 'r')


    table = BeautifulSoup(open('YEARS/' + str(y) + '.html','r').read()).find('table')
    df = pd.read_html(table)
```

Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend using pyQuery to parse and read inside html tags inside your html files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas' `.read_html()`, you don't need to use beautifulsoup to find the table tags. Pandas does that for you. You're also doing a ton of work to first save the html, then parse the html. Why not parse the html straight a way, and then if you wanted, just save that table?

Then you can plot using the table.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import random

headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
for year in range (1977, 2020, 1):

    tmp = random.random()*5.0
    print ('Sleep for ', tmp, ' seconds')
    time.sleep(tmp)

    url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/IND/'+ str(year) +'_games.html'

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    tables = pd.read_html(url)
    table = tables[0]

    table = table[table['G'] != 'G']
    table = table[['Unnamed: 5', 'Opponent','Unnamed: 7','Tm','Opp']]
    table.columns = ['Where','Opponent','WL','PacerScore','OpponentScore']
    table['Where'] = np.where(table.Where == '@', 'Away', 'Home')
    print ('Download table from :', url)

    table.to_csv('YEARS/' + str(year) + '.csv')
```

Your table will look like this, they you can just do:

```
x = table['PacerScore']
y = table['OpponentScore']
```

to get your x and y values for your scatter plot.

**Output:**

```
print (table.to_string())
   Where                Opponent   WL PacerScore OpponentScore  Season
0   Home       Memphis Grizzlies    W        111            83    2019
1   Away         Milwaukee Bucks    L        101           118    2019
2   Home           Brooklyn Nets    W        132           112    2019
3   Away  Minnesota Timberwolves    L         91           101    2019
4   Away       San Antonio Spurs    W        116            96    2019
5   Away     Cleveland Cavaliers    W        119           107    2019
6   Home  Portland Trail Blazers    L         93           103    2019
7   Away         New York Knicks    W        107           101    2019
8   Away           Chicago Bulls    W        107           105    2019
9   Home          Boston Celtics    W        102           101    2019
10  Home         Houston Rockets    L         94            98    2019
11  Home      Philadelphia 76ers    L         94           100    2019
12  Away              Miami Heat    W        110           102    2019
13  Away         Houston Rockets    L        103           115    2019
14  Home              Miami Heat    W         99            91    2019
15  Home           Atlanta Hawks    W         97            89    2019
16  Home               Utah Jazz    W        121            94    2019
17  Away       Charlotte Hornets    L        109           127    2019
18  Home       San Antonio Spurs    L        100           111    2019
19  Away               Utah Jazz    W        121            88    2019
21  Away            Phoenix Suns    W        109           104    2019
22  Away      Los Angeles Lakers    L         96           104    2019
23  Away        Sacramento Kings    L        110           111    2019
24  Home           Chicago Bulls    W         96            90    2019
25  Away           Orlando Magic    W        112            90    2019
26  Home        Sacramento Kings    W        107            97    2019
27  Home      Washington Wizards    W        109           101    2019
28  Home         Milwaukee Bucks    W        113            97    2019
29  Away      Philadelphia 76ers    W        113           101    2019
30  Home         New York Knicks    W        110            99    2019
31  Home     Cleveland Cavaliers    L         91            92    2019
32  Away         Toronto Raptors    L         96            99    2019
33  Away           Brooklyn Nets    W        114           106    2019
34  Home      Washington Wizards    W        105            89    2019
35  Away           Atlanta Hawks    W        129           121    2019
36  Home         Detroit Pistons    W        125            88    2019
37  Home           Atlanta Hawks    W        116           108    2019
38  Away           Chicago Bulls    W        119           116    2019
39  Away         Toronto Raptors    L        105           121    2019
40  Away     Cleveland Cavaliers    W        123           115    2019
42  Away          Boston Celtics    L        108           135    2019
43  Away         New York Knicks    W        121           106    2019
44  Home            Phoenix Suns    W        131            97    2019
45  Home      Philadelphia 76ers    L         96           120    2019
46  Home        Dallas Mavericks    W        111            99    2019
47  Home       Charlotte Hornets    W        120            95    2019
48  Home         Toronto Raptors    W        110           106    2019
49  Away       Memphis Grizzlies    L        103           106    2019
50  Home   Golden State Warriors    L        100           132    2019
51  Away      Washington Wizards    L         89           107    2019
52  Away           Orlando Magic    L        100           107    2019
53  Away              Miami Heat    W         95            88    2019
54  Away    New Orleans Pelicans    W        109           107    2019
55  Home      Los Angeles Lakers    W        136            94    2019
56  Home    Los Angeles Clippers    W        116            92    2019
57  Home     Cleveland Cavaliers    W        105            90    2019
58  Home       Charlotte Hornets    W         99            90    2019
59  Home         Milwaukee Bucks    L         97           106    2019
60  Home    New Orleans Pelicans    W        126           111    2019
61  Away      Washington Wizards    W        119           112    2019
63  Away         Detroit Pistons    L        109           113    2019
64  Away        Dallas Mavericks    L        101           110    2019
65  Home  Minnesota Timberwolves    W        122           115    2019
66  Home           Orlando Magic    L        112           117    2019
67  Home           Chicago Bulls    W        105            96    2019
68  Away         Milwaukee Bucks    L         98           117    2019
69  Away      Philadelphia 76ers    L         89           106    2019
70  Home         New York Knicks    W        103            98    2019
71  Home   Oklahoma City Thunder    W        108           106    2019
72  Away          Denver Nuggets    L        100           102    2019
73  Away  Portland Trail Blazers    L         98           106    2019
74  Away    Los Angeles Clippers    L        109           115    2019
75  Away   Golden State Warriors    L         89           112    2019
76  Home          Denver Nuggets  NaN        NaN           NaN    2019
77  Away   Oklahoma City Thunder  NaN        NaN           NaN    2019
78  Away          Boston Celtics  NaN        NaN           NaN    2019
79  Home           Orlando Magic  NaN        NaN           NaN    2019
80  Home         Detroit Pistons  NaN        NaN           NaN    2019
81  Away         Detroit Pistons  NaN        NaN           NaN    2019
82  Home          Boston Celtics  NaN        NaN           NaN    2019
84  Home           Brooklyn Nets  NaN        NaN           NaN    2019
85  Away           Atlanta Hawks  NaN        NaN           NaN    2019
```